# Unresolved reference: Dependencies

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

Создаю проект KMM и получаю ошибку unresolved reference: Dependencies
Создавал класс с таким именем: Dependencies.kt вот его код:

```
object Dependencies {

    object Kotlin {
        private const val version ="1.6.21"
        const val gradlePlugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version"
    }

    object Compose {
        private const val version ="1.1.1"
        const val gradlePlugin = "org.jetbrains.compose:compose-gradle-plugin:$version"
    }

    object Android {
        const val gradlePlugin = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1"
    }


}
```

А build.gradle.kts в директории buildSrc вот его код:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    maven(url = "https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Dependencies.Kotlin.gradlePlugin)
    implementation(Dependencies.Compose.gradlePlugin)
    implementation(Dependencies.Android.gradlePlugin)
}
```

Он не видит object Dependencies